# Link between Automated market makers and Logarithmic scoring rules

Tags: markets

In most articles I read about AMMs (automated market makers), there is a link or a mention to Hanson's work about the Logarithmic scoring rule. But I don't clearly see the link between AMM's and the LMSR. Can someone help me ?